# Should I use babel preset 'stage-2'?

Tags: webpack, babeljs, babel-6

I had to install babel dynamic import plugin and as a result I also added 'stage-2' to presets array. 
From the documentation I see that preset 'stage-2' already includes dynamic import plugin
https://babeljs.io/docs/en/6.26.3/babel-preset-stage-2

and also according to docs stage presets are described as following:

> stage-0 - Strawman: just an idea, possible Babel plugin.
>
> stage-1 - Proposal: this is worth working on.
>
> **stage-2 - Draft: initial spec.**
>
> stage-3 - Candidate: complete spec and initial browser
>   implementations.
>
> stage-4 - Finished: will be added to the next yearly release.

So my questions are:

- Why I had to install the plugin separately if it's already included?
- Is it safe to use 'stage-2'? Where can I check browser support for
  it?

I'm using babel 6.23.0, webpack 3